# Python protocols. Is defining initializer arguments a correct way?

Tags: python, oop, abstract-class

I create some abstraction for future objects. I already know that each of them need to have another objects passed as arguments during initialization.

My current solution looks like this.

```
class Action(Protocol):
    def __init__(self, element_finder: ElementFinder, night_club: NightClub, pharmacy: Pharmacy):
        pass
        
    def do_action(self):
        pass
    
    def restore(self):
        pass
```

I don't like it to be fair because still I will need to bound this arguments with my instance like `self.element_finder = finder` etc... May be I should use ABC and predefined init? Appreciate any hints :)

Comment: It doesn't necessarily need to be an ABC, but you probably do want just a regular base class you can inherit from. The purpose of a protocol is to let you define a function like `def foo(x: Action): ...`, and not worry about the type of `x` or how it was created or works, as long as i has `do_action` and `restore` methods.

Comment: (That is, protocols are for type-checking only, providing a way to implement structure subtyping instead of the nominal subtyping provided by inheritance.)

Comment: @chepner So just skip init abstract right?

Comment: Probably, unless you are somehow passing a *class* as an argument in order to create instances.

Comment: Nah, I'm passing already instantiated objects :) Thanks!

Comment: Sometimes you do want a protocol to also cover initialization, and nothing to inherit from a base class but really only enforce an interface, which here we call a protocol. In what sense would that be against the design of python's protocols?